# How to display the button to the bottom of the texview in popup?

Tags: android

I am able to create button and pop-up but the button in the pop-up is displayed above the the text in the pop-up.

My intention is to display the that button at the end of the pop-up that is the bottom of the text in the popup.

my code is:

```
    public void init() {
    popupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    popupText = new WebView(this);
    popupText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first);
    popupText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    popupText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    popupText.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    insidePopupButton = new Button(this);
    layoutOfPopup = new LinearLayout(this);
    insidePopupButton.setText("log out button");
    insidePopupButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myborder);
    LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutOfPopup.addView(insidePopupButton, lpView);

    String text = "<html><body style=\"text-align:justify\"> %s </body></Html>";
    String summary = "Like 'I am right, you are wrong', dominating or refusing to be dominated, all these games are played by the ego.Very often, we find the inauthentic self is what is at play. </body></html>";
    popupText.loadData(String.format(text, summary), "text/html", "utf-8");
    popupText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first);
    layoutOfPopup.setOrientation(1);
    layoutOfPopup.addView(popupText);
    layoutOfPopup.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first);


    public void popupInit() {
    popupButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    insidePopupButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    popupMessage = new PopupWindow(layoutOfPopup, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    popupMessage.setContentView(layoutOfPopup);

}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding view in different order like this:

```
layoutOfPopup = new LinearLayout(this);
...
layoutOfPopup.addView(popupText);
...
layoutOfPopup.addView(insidePopupButton, lpView);
```

Comment: yes. It is worked for high width and height devices. But when I scroll the pop-up window to read the text on the window in small devices the button is not displayed.